# mysqldump fails with result code 3

Tags: mysql

I am running mysqldump and getting a result code 3 on a specific table.

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump" --host='localhost' --user='myuser' --password='mypass' --opt --complete-insert --max_allowed_packet=64M --result-file='/home/me/backup/db_20171003104656.sql' mydb 2>&1
```

The error message it outputs is:

```
 Result code: 3
 valueA: mysqldump: Error 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query when dumping table `foo` at row: 5217
```

The 5217 is not consistent; it varies each time.

When I remove the table temporarily from the database, the backup works.

I have tried the following:

- adding max_allowed_packet
- using set_time_limit(0);
- running repair on the table.
- exporting the table as text, removing the original and recreating it.

I am passing in an options file to mysqldump with the following:

```
[mysqld]
net_read_timeout=300
net_write_timeout=300
connect_timeout=300
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I might fix this?

Comment: Was there an error message as mysqldump exited with status 3? I'm looking at the source, and it looks like every case that would cause exit with status 3 prints an error message. But there are multiple cases where this happens. Tip: when asking about an error on Stack Overflow, you should include the exact text of the error message.

Comment: I was so focused on enumerating all the things I tried that I forgot that!  Updated.

Comment: The error of losing the connection is often due to insufficient max packet size, in my experience.
I would try `--max_allowed_packet=1G`. Your setting of 64M may not be enough given the data in your database.

Comment: Nope - tried 1G and even 4G and got the same error.

Comment: This bug suggests increasing `net_read_timeout` and `net_write_timeout`. https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=46103 Also this dba issue: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/97846/mysqldump-error-2013

Comment: It's also rarely possible that you have some physical corruption in the database, and the mysqld process is actually crashing whenever it tries to read the corrupted table. Examine your mysql error log, and check `show global status like 'uptime'` to see if it's restarting.

Comment: Mysql is not crashing; uptime is increasing before vs after mysqldump.  Changing net_read and net_write looks interesting but those require SUPER privileges.  I'll see if there's a way around that.